# Android: Unittest method which use Firebase

Tags: android, unit-testing, firebase, mockito, powermock

#### Problem Description

I need to unit test function which uses Firebase Object like it is shown in the source code below.

#### Question

What is the best way to write unit test?
Is it really needed to unit test functions like that?

#### Source code

```
void foo() { 
    Firebase f = new Firebase("url").child("child1").child("child2");
    if (f != null)
        f.setValue(state);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Firebase itself, but I would extract `interface` for everything connected to Firebase, then I would create an implementation of that `interface` with Firebase (e.g. `FirebaseData`). Operating on just interface I would test my logic without knowing the real implementation of Firebase.

It is always worth to test your code, because:

1. Test proves valid logic
2. Helps testing regression/refactors
3. Testing improves your design

I really recommend watching video by J.B. Rainsberger [Integrated tests are scam](https://vimeo.com/80533536)

Operating on `interface` has one more great advantage: You always will be able to change your implementation without breaking the contract.

Comment: jakubbialkowski: not quite, as the video itself states, you also need to test the "right" side of the contract boundary.  since -- unlike say the google app engine -- there currently does not exist a "local" version of firebase (ie the firebase platform that you can run locally as part of a unit test), you must resort to writing such tests against either an actual production firebase instance (yuck) or perhaps create an unpaid account and try there... it's really crappy.  Let me know if you've been able to solve that... I've posed the question and no one from Firebase/Google has replied